# Install all correct Drivers on UBUNTU 14.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I am newbie in the Ubuntu world. I read about this magnificent OS and I want to get started

I have installed Ubuntu along with Windows 7 (on a 64bit laptop)

My laptop specs are

- Intel Core 2 Duo T7700 2,
- 4GB RAM
- Nvidia Geforce 8700M GT
- Realtek Sound
- Realtek Ethernet
- Realtek Wireless

I want to know how do i install all my drivers?
Were i can learn how to do it properly and correct?
Do i need to install all this drivers? Or just the Graphic Card??
This is so different then windows? Or is more simple to achieve the correct installations?

Any help i appreciate.
Thanks

PS: I think i will stay on Ubuntu.. I am sick of Windows and all their bugs and crashes..

Comment: what does this command 'lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' does?

Comment: And output of this command 'lspci -vnn | grep Network'?

Comment: @Ashu No, no, no, don't scare the newb. Just answer his question.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Windows, Linux systems generally come with all the needed drivers/modules. So it's basically plug and play: you insert something in your machine, it works.

But some companies like NVidia and AMD produce proprietary, optimized drivers. You can install them using Ubuntu's preinstalled "Additional drivers" program, search for it in the dash.

Proprietary drivers usually give more performance than their generic, open source ones, because they are made by the manufacturers themselves. But the system and your hardware should work fine without them.

Comment: Hello Eduardo Cola.

Comment: Oi, mate! What's up?

Comment: i have post some answer to your reply. Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to install drivers at all as the kernel supports most hardware ; only thing you need to install on recent gpus like amd or intel are their propietary drivers wich you can easily do by looking in dash for the drivers utility and then select the propietary driver and click install.  (no need to do this for Intel old nvidia or radeon integrated gpus).